# Error on editing AuraDefinitionBundle DeveloperNames

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Whatever I try to change a component name (via Query Editor `[SELECT Id, developerName FROM AuraDefinitionBundle]`), the following error raises:

```
[object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: *6530961-45081* (887406290)
```

Being or not in use doesn't change the error. Any help appreciated.

Also is it possible to somehow add namespaces to them also? (namespaceprefix) All components created within my sandbox don't have any, and the fields don't allow editing.

Comment: I have had this same issue.. did you ever find a solution to renaming?

Answer (score 2):

It can be quite a hassle to change a name of a Lightning Component. I would recreate it with the correct name and delete the other one.

Please note that you should delete all references to the old component. Also of inactive Lightning Pages. Otherwise you would not be able to delete it.

Regarding the namespace prefix. This is only used for [managed packages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=about_managed_packages.htm&type=5).

> A managed package is a collection of application components that are posted as a unit on AppExchange, and are associated with a namespace and a License Management Organization.

Comment: According to https://www.codescience.com/blog/2017/how-to-rename-lightning-component-bundles, you should be able to just rename the bundle directly via query